# Deploy button is hidden in cloudkit dashboard when deployng changes to production

Tags: cloudkit

As you can see on the picture below there is no possibility to deploy to production. Any workarounds?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just find out a way to show "deploy" button.

If you are using Google Chrome as your browser, try the following steps:

1.click "View" on Chrome menu (On the top) -> Click "Developer" -> Click "Developer Tools"

2.Press "command" and "F" at the same time. Enter "**button**". Press "return" to see the results until "Deploy" button shows!

[image]
*My chrome version is Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)*

I think Apple might solve the problem soon. Until then, you can try my solution. Hope this helps you!